# Can a solidity contract count how many times it has been instantiated?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

After the deployment of the contract, let's say MyContract, can we literally count how many times MyContract has been instantiated?

Here's the code of MyContract:

```
contract MyContract {
  uint public counter = 0;

  function MyContract() public {
    counter++;
  }
}
```

After the deployment, which I used `truffle deploy`, I do the following code to instantiate a new MyContract instance, inside `truffle console`:

```
MyContract.new()
          .then(function(c){return c.counter.call()})
          .then(console.log)
```

I expected every time I execute this line, I will have an increment on the `counter`, which looks like `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,... by steps.

But I keep on receive `1` as the result, without any changes. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating a new contract instance every time. There is no way for each contract instance to be aware of how many other ones have been created, so the value will always be 1.

What you want to do is have a parent contract which is able to create the child contract that you would like to count. Here is some sample code:

```
contract Parent {
    uint counter;

    function createChild() {
        Child child = new Child();
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

And the Child contract could be anything you want. I think this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you instantiate/deploy your contract it is a new contract with new storage, so it is correctly reporting that it it has been created once. Each contract has its own independent version of `counter`.

You could have a single Counter contract that each of the contracts you deploy calls as it is created. That would be able to maintain a single counter that increments each time.  I don't know how you could protect that from being called by any third-party, though, and messing up your count.

Or, perhaps best, you should make a "Factory" contract that only takes instruction from your own account. When you call it, it deploys your contract itself and keeps count for you.